# Why do we need to specify tsx while importing using NextJS?

Tags: next.js

I struggled a lot to find out why

`import Accordion from '../components/Accordion';`

was not working. When I changed it to this using trial-and-error, it worked.

`import Accordion from '../components/Accordion.tsx';`

Why do I need to include .tsx in NextJS for import ?

Comment: You might have another file in the same directory called `Accordion.{some-extension}`. Which version of Next are you using too, btw?

Comment: This isn't necessarily required actually. It's possible posting your tsconfig file would help answer why this is required. Does your repo's configuration files look similar to this? https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/deprecated-main/examples/with-typescript

Comment: I have only one file Accordion.tsx in components. I am using the latest version of NextJS because I created it a few days ago - I think 12.1 ?

Comment: My question about configuration is making sure that your tsconfig in particular looks like their example. If it doesn't I could see the pathname becoming an issue. https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/canary/examples/with-typescript/tsconfig.json

Comment: But I don't see any tsconfig file. I have next.config.js which has `reactStrictMode: true` and a styles/tailwind.config.js

Comment: You might want to add a `tsconfig.json` file then.

Comment: Does it not come with `npx create-next-app@latest --typescript` by default ? I don't remember ifI had given --typescript or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because NextJS assumes it to be a folder name. So, if you want to
import your component like `import Accordion from '../components/Accordion';`,
then you need to make `Accordion` a folder and add your typescript code in a file named `index.tsx` inside the `Accordion` folder. This also helps in adding other files related to the accordion component like `styles.module.scss` or any test files.